# For counter variable not working in the if else statement

Tags: javascript, api, for-loop, if-statement

The **i** variable from the **for** counter works when getting each API for each Twitch streamer, however when I use it to generate divs it just comes out as 8. Is there a way I can make the counter work when getting the API data and iterating through the streamers?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

// streamers I want to look up

 var streamers = ["ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2", "cretetion", "freecodecamp", "storbeck", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas"]

// counts the number of streamers in the array

  for (var i = 0; i < streamers.length; i++){

// gets each streamer, one by one

  $.getJSON("https://wind-bow.gomix.me/twitch-api/streams/" + streamers[i] +"?callback=?", function(json) {

//if they are not offline, pulls information from them and adds it to a div

if ((json.stream) !== null) {
  $("#results").prepend("<div class = \"resultsONLINE\">" + json.stream.channel.display_name + "</div>");

// if they are offline, marks them as offline

} else {
  $("#results").append("<div class = \"resultsOFFLINE\">" + streamers[i] + " is offline</div>");

}


  });

  };
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // streamers I want to look up

     var streamers = ["ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2", "cretetion", "freecodecamp", "storbeck", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas"]

    // counts the number of streamers in the array
      var index = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < streamers.length; i++){

    // gets each streamer, one by one

      $.getJSON("https://wind-bow.gomix.me/twitch-api/streams/" + streamers[i] +"?callback=?", function(json) {

    //if they are not offline, pulls information from them and adds it to a div

    if ((json.stream) !== null) {
      $("#results").prepend("<div class = \"resultsONLINE\">" + json.stream.channel.display_name + "</div>");

    // if they are offline, marks them as offline

    } else {
      $("#results").append("<div class = \"resultsOFFLINE\">" + streamers[index] + " is offline</div>");

    }
    index++;


      });

      };
```

Comment: Worked! This is really clever and simple, totally going to use this in the future, thanks for your help!

Comment: Wait, now it gives me different results every time I run it?!? Sometimes saying streamers are both online and offline, and sometimes getting it right, but with no changing variables how is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, getJSON is a promise based function, so try to use .then(json => function() ...).

This code should work properly.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // streamers I want to look up
  var streamers = [
    "ESL_SC2",
    "OgamingSC2",
    "cretetion",
    "freecodecamp",
    "storbeck",
    "habathcx",
    "RobotCaleb",
    "noobs2ninjas"
  ];

  // counts the number of streamers in the array
  var streamerLength = streamers.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < streamerLength; i++) {
    // gets each streamer, one by one
    $.getJSON(
      "https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/streams/" + streamers[i]
    ).then(json => appendStreamerInfo(json));
  }

  function appendStreamerInfo(json) {
    //if they are not offline, pulls information from them and adds it to a div
    if (json.stream !== null) {
      $("#results").prepend(
        '<div class = "resultsONLINE">' +
          json.stream.channel.display_name +
          "</div>"
      );

      // if they are offline, marks them as offline
    } else {
      $("#results").append(
        '<div class = "resultsOFFLINE">' + streamers[i] + " is offline</div>"
      );
    }
  }
});
```